# How to create a Byte Buddy proxy with MethodDelegation or Forwarding?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I get an exception in the load call when I try to do the following:

```
  Field datasourceExtensionField = Grid.class.getDeclaredField("datasourceExtension");
  datasourceExtensionField.setAccessible(true);
  RpcDataProviderExtension rpcDataProviderExtension = (RpcDataProviderExtension) datasourceExtensionField.get(grid);

  Field activeItemHandlerField = RpcDataProviderExtension.class.getDeclaredField("activeItemHandler");
  activeItemHandlerField.setAccessible(true);
  Object activeItemHandler = activeItemHandlerField.get(rpcDataProviderExtension);

  Field keyMapperField = activeItemHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyMapper");
  keyMapperField.setAccessible(true);
  KeyMapper original = (KeyMapper) keyMapperField.get(activeItemHandler);

  KeyMapper wrapper = new ByteBuddy() //
      .subclass(KeyMapper.class) //
      .defineField("original", KeyMapper.class, Visibility.PUBLIC) //
      .method(ElementMatchers.any()) //
      .intercept(Forwarding.toField("original")) //
      .method(ElementMatchers.named("get")) //
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new KeyMapperWrapper(grid, original))) //
      .make() //
      .load(KeyMapperWrapper.class.getClassLoader()) //
      .getLoaded() //
      .newInstance();

  // give wrapper the reference to the original
  wrapper.getClass().getDeclaredField("original").set(wrapper, original);

  // replace original with wrapper
  keyMapperField.set(activeItemHandler, wrapper);
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad access to protected data in invokevirtual
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/vaadin/server/KeyMapper$ByteBuddy$WlWljaQa.clone()Ljava/lang/Object; @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/vaadin/server/KeyMapper' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/vaadin/server/KeyMapper$ByteBuddy$WlWljaQa'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/vaadin/server/KeyMapper$ByteBuddy$WlWljaQa' }
    stack: { 'com/vaadin/server/KeyMapper' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 000c b600 1cb0                    

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$ForStaticField.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:101)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$Compound.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:180)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:75)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4525)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4514)
    at test.KeyMapperWrapper.patch(KeyMapperWrapper.java:62)
```

I'm apparently not understanding how `Forwarding` is supposed to work, what am I doing wrong?

My intention is to replace the existing `KeyMapper` with a proxy where I *override* one single method, and delegate the rest to the original.

Edit: I now also tried with `MethodDelegation`, which throws the same exception:

```
 .method(ElementMatchers.any()) //
 .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(original)) //
 .method(ElementMatchers.named("get")) //
 .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new KeyMapperWrapper(grid, original))) //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Byte Buddy. The type you are however trying to create is not legal, Byte Buddy fails to provide you a proper error message. When subclassing, it is legitimate to override `protected` methods. It is however not always legal to invoke these methods on another type due to visibility constraints. When you are forwarding a call, you can therefore only override `public` methods. What you want to do is to match:

```
.method(ElementMatchers.isPublic())
```

where the error does not longer occur. I already added a fix to provide you this error message in the next release version (1.5.8) of Byte Buddy.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this! The type I try to subclass only has public methods, so shouldn't it be legal? But the next proxy I need might not have all public methods, so maybe it is anyway better to use the InvocationHandlerAdapter? (and use method.setAccessible(true) before invoking)

Comment: It inherits the methods from `Object`. The problematic method in question was `Object::clone` as you can see from the verifier error.

Comment: I see, thank you! I think I will stick with the InvocationHandlerAdapter approach.

Comment: I just released the new version. If you aim for performance, note that the forwarding is much more efficient then the invocation handler. Also, note that the invocation handler adapter would cause a runtime exception if `clone` would be invoked.

Comment: My override is probably the biggest performance killer here... Would it throw an exception for clone even if I called method.setAccessible(true)? When changing library internals like this, I'd prefer to delegate the non-public methods as well, with the hope to keep the internal state correct.

Comment: No, with accessibility, you can invoke methods that you could not otherwise. This sort of access cannot be legally expressed in byte code. The performance killer is probably the megamorphic dispatch from the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with InvocationHandlerAdapter. Still don't understand why my original attempts didn't work, though.

```
public class KeyMapperProxyHandler implements InvocationHandler
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private static final Logger LOGGER              = Logger.getLogger(KeyMapperProxyHandler.class.getName());

  private Grid                m_grid              = null;
  private KeyMapper           m_originalKeyMapper = null;

  public KeyMapperProxyHandler(Grid grid, KeyMapper originalKeyMapper)
  {
    m_grid = grid;
    m_originalKeyMapper = originalKeyMapper;
  }

  /**
   * call after container data source has been set
   */
  public static void patch(Grid grid)
  {
    try
    {
      Field datasourceExtensionField = Grid.class.getDeclaredField("datasourceExtension");
      datasourceExtensionField.setAccessible(true);
      RpcDataProviderExtension rpcDataProviderExtension = (RpcDataProviderExtension) datasourceExtensionField.get(grid);

      Field activeItemHandlerField = RpcDataProviderExtension.class.getDeclaredField("activeItemHandler");
      activeItemHandlerField.setAccessible(true);
      Object activeItemHandler = activeItemHandlerField.get(rpcDataProviderExtension);

      Field keyMapperField = activeItemHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyMapper");
      keyMapperField.setAccessible(true);
      KeyMapper original = (KeyMapper) keyMapperField.get(activeItemHandler);

      KeyMapperProxyHandler proxyHandler = new KeyMapperProxyHandler(grid, original);

      KeyMapper proxy = new ByteBuddy() //
          .subclass(KeyMapper.class) //
          .method(ElementMatchers.any()) //
          .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(proxyHandler)) //
          .method(ElementMatchers.named("get")) //
          .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(proxyHandler)) //
          .make() //
          .load(KeyMapperProxyHandler.class.getClassLoader()) //
          .getLoaded() //
          .newInstance();

      keyMapperField.set(activeItemHandler, proxy);
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
  }

  /**
   * override for get method
   */
  public Object get(String key)
  {
    Object staleItemId = m_originalKeyMapper.get(key);
    Optional freshItemId = m_grid.getContainerDataSource().getItemIds().stream().filter(i -> i.equals(staleItemId)).findAny();
    //    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "intercept: stale=" + staleItemId + ", fresh=" + freshItemId);
    return freshItemId.isPresent() ? freshItemId.get() : null;
  }

  /**
   * proxy all other methods
   */
  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
  {
    return method.invoke(m_originalKeyMapper, args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question I asked, but rather two more alternative solutions to my problem:

I convinced myself that I could replace the desired object reference at a time point where it has not been in use yet. So I decided to not delegate/proxy anything, and throw the original object instance away, completely replacing it with the byte buddy dynamic type:

```
public class GridKeyMapperPatch
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GridKeyMapperPatch.class.getName());

  private Grid                m_grid = null;

  public GridKeyMapperPatch(Grid grid)
  {
    m_grid = grid;
  }

  /**
   * call immediately after setting container data source
   */
  public static void patch(Grid grid)
  {
    try
    {
      GridKeyMapperPatch gridKeyMapperPatch = new GridKeyMapperPatch(grid);

      KeyMapper patchedKeyMapper = new ByteBuddy() //
          .subclass(KeyMapper.class) //
          .method(ElementMatchers.named("get")) //
          .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(gridKeyMapperPatch)) //
          .make() //
          .load(GridKeyMapperPatch.class.getClassLoader()) //
          .getLoaded() //
          .newInstance();

      Field datasourceExtensionField = Grid.class.getDeclaredField("datasourceExtension");
      datasourceExtensionField.setAccessible(true);
      RpcDataProviderExtension rpcDataProviderExtension = (RpcDataProviderExtension) datasourceExtensionField.get(grid);

      Field activeItemHandlerField = RpcDataProviderExtension.class.getDeclaredField("activeItemHandler");
      activeItemHandlerField.setAccessible(true);
      Object activeItemHandler = activeItemHandlerField.get(rpcDataProviderExtension);

      Field keyMapperField = activeItemHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyMapper");
      keyMapperField.setAccessible(true);
      keyMapperField.set(activeItemHandler, patchedKeyMapper);
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
  }

  public Object get(@SuperCall Callable superCall, String key) throws Exception
  {
    Object staleItemId = superCall.call();
    Optional freshItemId = m_grid.getContainerDataSource().getItemIds().stream().filter(i -> i.equals(staleItemId)).findAny();
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "intercept: stale=" + staleItemId + ", fresh=" + freshItemId);
    return freshItemId.isPresent() ? freshItemId.get() : null;
  }
}
```

Taking a step back, I then found that, since the class and method in question were public, I could just normally subclass it:

```
public class GridTools
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GridTools.class.getName());

  /**
   * call immediately after setting container data source
   */
  public static void replaceKeyMapper(Grid grid) throws Exception
  {
    Field datasourceExtensionField = Grid.class.getDeclaredField("datasourceExtension");
    datasourceExtensionField.setAccessible(true);
    RpcDataProviderExtension rpcDataProviderExtension = (RpcDataProviderExtension) datasourceExtensionField.get(grid);

    Field activeItemHandlerField = RpcDataProviderExtension.class.getDeclaredField("activeItemHandler");
    activeItemHandlerField.setAccessible(true);
    Object activeItemHandler = activeItemHandlerField.get(rpcDataProviderExtension);

    Field keyMapperField = activeItemHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyMapper");
    keyMapperField.setAccessible(true);
    keyMapperField.set(activeItemHandler, new NonCachingKeyMapper(grid));
  }

  private static class NonCachingKeyMapper extends KeyMapper
  {
    private Grid m_grid = null;

    public NonCachingKeyMapper(Grid grid)
    {
      m_grid = grid;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String key)
    {
      Object staleItemId = super.get(key);
      Optional freshItemId = m_grid.getContainerDataSource().getItemIds().stream().filter(i -> i.equals(staleItemId)).findAny();
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "intercept: stale=" + staleItemId + ", fresh=" + freshItemId);
      return freshItemId.isPresent() ? freshItemId.get() : null;
    }
  }
}
```